Can SSRS Extension Run on Visual Studio in ARM Windows 11 on M2 MacBook?
I'm planning to upgrade from an Intel-based MacBook to an Apple M2 MacBook. My setup will include:

Installing MS SQL Server in Docker on the local machine.
Running ARM Windows 11 using Parallels Desktop.

I would like to know if the SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) extension can run on Visual Studio in this environment. Specifically, will the SSRS extension work properly on Visual Studio installed on ARM Windows 11?
Any insights or experiences with this setup would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I found the answer
The SSRS 2022 can't be installed on the visual studio 2022 ARM version.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022&ssr=false#qna
